# How to convert Float to String in robotframework

Tags: test-automation-framework, robot

I have a list with data as float or number and I need to convert it to String for comparison with robotframework with another dataset which is in String only.

I tierd string operations from robotframework but I didn't found anything to  convert float to String.

Comment: Float to String conversion is a question that should be asked on other boards.

Comment: I disagree with this being off-topic.  Robotframework is a keyword driven testing framework.  We answer plenty of questions about Selenium here, so I'm not sure why a programming question specific to Robotframework is off-topic.

Comment: Any help would be appreciated regarding question

Comment: How are you getting floats?  Can you show some code.  Robotframework seems to go out of its way to treat most data as a string unless you ask it otherwise.  Would you be able to post some very simple Roboframework code that shows the problem you're having?

Comment: I am getting float values from a excel sheet while I am comparing it with list in robotframework which has same data as sheet but string type.

Comment: How? Show us some Robot code :)

Comment: Please edit your question to add the Robot code that you are using to try to convert your data to string

Comment: Thank you for sharing feedback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation I expect any "item" to be able to `Convert To String`: https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Convert%20To%20String

Maybe you should first `Convert To Number`, those seem Floats: https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Convert%20To%20Number

Comment: Yes, after some trial and runs I was able to convert float to String via convert to Number